# Pandas prepend data to multi-indexed series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following pandas.Series object with the following data:

```
country        year
United States  2004     416.205383
               2005     430.326178
               2006     444.208260
               2007     456.880067
               2009     472.733367
               2008     474.420151
               2010     480.486400
               2011     495.654594
               2012     505.911360
               2013     513.322114
Name: FP.CPI.TOTL, dtype: float64
```

Let's call it cpi. I'd like to prepend the year 2014 to this series, but instead use the string name 'TTM'.

cpi.index is

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'United States'], [u'2004', u'2005', u'2006', u'2007', u'2008', u'2009', u'2010', u'2011', u'2012', u'2013']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
           names=[u'country', u'year'])
```

and cpi.values is

```
array([  416.20538282,   430.32617782,   444.20825976,   456.88006655,
         472.73336741,   474.42015054,   480.4864    ,   495.65459441,
         505.91135964,   513.32211444,  1000.        ])
```

I tried

```
row = pd.Series(100,index=['TTM'])
cpi.append(row)
```

but it appends to the wrong level within the MultiIndex. From here, I could construct a new array of values, a new MultiIndex, and then a new DataFrame, but that seems pretty wasteful. Is there an easier way?